# Sum specific numbers in a column (Google sheets)

Tags: google-sheets

I have the following spreadsheet containing information about some courses.

[image]

I would like to sum the `ECTS` column but also group the sums by their type `General` or `Tech`. E.g here I would have end up with two cells. One containing the number 5 (Total sum of ECTS for courses with type `Tech`) and another cell containing the number 27.5 (Total sum of ECTS for courses with type `General`).

Can this be achieved somehow?

Comment: Yeah, think `Query()` is your friend here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Formula:

`=query(B19:C23, "select sum(B) group by C", -1 )`

[image]

Everything in the image should be self descriptive.

Comment: Thanks, I actually ended up solving using SUMIF function

Comment: That works too! It will do the bare minimum but if you need more modification of the data,  feel free to use `query`. Also, take heed of kirkg13's answer below. You can choose the order of the output of the query by column if that is needed.

Comment: Can you modify this to show the type in the cell next to the sum?

Comment: @BorisGrunwald `=query(B19:C23, "select sum(B), C group by C", -1 )`. If you want the type before the sum, use `=query(B19:C23, "select C, sum(B) group by C", -1 )`

Answer (score 3):

Boris, here is a general formula:

```
=query(A1:E,"select E,sum(C) where E<>'' group by E",1)
```

This would return a mini-table of the results.

To get just the two cells, modify the above formula to this

```
=query(A2:E,"select sum(C) where E<>'' group by E 
               order by sum(C) label sum(C) '' ",0)
```

You might need to sort them ("order by") a different column to get them in the order your want - this sorts them by increasing value.

**UPDATE:**
Further explanation of the formula:

"   where E<>''  " is effectively saying where (column) E is not equal to blank.  It is important to note that query only works reliably with consistent data - only numbers or only text/strings in each column.  It will still run if you have mixed data, but the results can be surprising, and query tends to look at what the majority of the data in a column is, either text or numberic.

So the above test will only work for a text column.  If you are looking for numbers, you would not use the single quotes, just the equal sign.  Eg.  `where E <> 0`    would find rows with numbers not equal to zero in column E.

`order by`  does sorting of the resuslts by one or more columns, and can specify ascending or descending order.

And `label sum(C) ''`  turns off the column header that the query adds when you include an aggregating function like "sum".  Or it can be used to re-label the default heading to something else - `label sum(C) 'Calculated Sum'`

References:

[Query](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en) - general usage

[Query](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage) - detailed reference

[image]

Comment: upvoted for the `order by`. Great addition to the answer that will improve the quality of data returned.

Comment: Thank you, very cool. Can you explain what `where E<>''` does?

Answer (score 1):

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(B1:B8="a"), A1:A8)
```

another way to do it using SUMPRODUCT function

[image]

- B1:B8 : checks for text "a"
- -- : the operator decodes True as 1 and False as 0.
- A1:A8 : Values to be taken and added